# Google places API getDetails() service not returning ratings for any location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I've been trying to build a bicycle assistant and I'm trying to show the phone number and rating for the destination the user enters.

I have some code that gets me the entire request in the form below (copied from firefox console)

```
address_components: Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
adr_address: "<span class=\"street-address\">Times Sq</span>, <span class=\"locality\">New York</span>, <span class=\"region\">NY</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">USA</span>"
​
formatted_address: "Times Sq, New York, NY, USA"
​
geometry: Object { location: {…}, viewport: {…} }
​
html_attributions: Array []
​
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png"
​
icon_background_color: "#7B9EB0"
​
icon_mask_base_uri: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet"
​
name: "Times Square"
​
place_id: "ChIJO8I76FVYwokR2nYv8Wdvie0"
​
reference: "ChIJO8I76FVYwokR2nYv8Wdvie0"
​
types: Array [ "route" ]
​
url: "https://maps.google.com/?q=Times+Sq,+New+York,+NY,+USA&ftid=0x89c25855e83bc23b:0xed896f67f12f76da"
​
utc_offset: 
​
utc_offset_minutes: -240
​
vicinity: "Manhattan"
```

I get legitimate details for all the place IDs I search for, such as phone number and address. However, I do not get the rating for any of them.

I tried popular places too but no ratings field. I haven't added any field filters either. Below is my setup for the request for reference.

```
function fetchmoredeets(addr) {
    var loc = addr.split(' ').join('+')
    const URL = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${loc}&key=(my_key)`
    // First get and parse the nearby regions

    async function fetcher(URL){
        const resp = await fetch(URL);
        return await resp.json()
    }

    var res, req;
    (async () => {
      req = await fetcher(URL);
      res = req.results;
      console.log("All deets helper:", res[0]);
      var deetsreq = {
              placeId: res[0].place_id,
            };

            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.getDetails(deetsreq, callback);

            function callback(place, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.log(place);
                document.getElementById("table-title").innerHTML = res[0].name
                var table = document.getElementById("deets-entries");
                var r = table.insertRow();
                r.insertCell().innerHTML =  place.address_components[1].short_name + ' ' + place.address_components[2].short_name; // addr

                r.insertCell().innerHTML= place.ratings; // rating
                if(place.formatted_phone_number==null){
                    r.insertCell().innerHTML= "NA";
                }
                else{
                    r.insertCell().innerHTML= place.formatted_phone_number;
                }
              }
            }


})()
}
```

Above, addr is a string with the address of the place (based on the user's selection from google's places autocomplete API)

Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The place id you used in your example (`ChIJO8I76FVYwokR2nYv8Wdvie0`) returns `"types" : [ "route" ]`. Routes don't have ratings.

Instead, use a place id of a business or other types of places that include ratings.

Using the [Place ID Finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) and searching for *Times Square* returns a different place id: `ChIJmQJIxlVYwokRLgeuocVOGVU`.

Doing a place details request with this place id:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJmQJIxlVYwokRLgeuocVOGVU&key=YOUR_API_KEY

returns `"types" : [ "tourist_attraction", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]` and `"rating" : 4.7`.